# when moving a div element down the background image gets moved as well

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project. I have gotten all of the rails aspect down without much of an issue. However, I ran into an issue with CSS-something that I normally do not encounter. Usually run into ruby problems!

Basically, I have a background image set on a page. At the top of that page, I have a div element. When I go to move the div element further down the page, the background image stays with it. It is almost as if the two are connected. Here is the code that I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="about_background">

 <div class="container heading_block">
    <h1 class="about_heading"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i> About Abby <i   
    class="fa fa-cutlery"></i></h1>
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.about_background {
background-image: url("bread.jpeg");
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

.heading_block {
background-color: rgba(200,100,175, 0.8);
border-radius: 35px;
}

.about_heading {
text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Please let me know what else is need. I tried setting something up on jsfiddle but was not getting what I needed. If you need to see the code, on github, it is under ravenusmc, food_blog. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are trying to move the div but this is what I usually use to move elements.

```
.heading_block {
position: relative;
top: 10px; //or however far you want to move it. 
background-color: rgba(200,100,175, 0.8);
border-radius: 35px;
 }
```

Comment: Got it-I seemed to have been leaving out the position: relative! It does work now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your point then just add...

`min-height: 100%;` to `about_background` class.

Comment: Tried that and still shifting down the page! It is a background image with a div element with an H1 tag in it. Every time I add margin-top: 55px; to the heading_block class then the background image will move down with the div element. Very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem you're having.

1. which of the divs are you moving? if it's the first (outer) then the background will move with it as it is attached to that container the `background-attachment` isn't going to change that, in fact if you re-size the window with this you'll see what it's actually doing is locking the position of the background to your screen and re-sizing the window will make it scroll inside of the container.
2. Moving the 2nd div (the inner) leaves the background in place in my test.

Perhaps attaching the background to the body instead if you must have it stay in place.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! It turns out that I was leaving off the position: relative. Once I added it, the div element moved down the page and the background image stayed. Thank you again!